# Woocommerce Product Vendors and ACF

Tags: woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF with Woocomerce Product Vendors, i have added an additional field group to the Edit Vendor page and the form is working fine, but when i use the same form, from the Vendor/Vendor Admin settings, the data is not fetching in the form and also the form is not updating any data to the frontend and backend. I have looked around in most of the documentations but with little or no luck. Any help would be very nice. Thanks

Comment: You are using ACF to add custom fields to a vendor(taxonomy). However, ACF does not have control over a Setting page added by Woocommerce Product Vendors. For this you will need some PHP knowledge and analyze the Woocommerce Product Vendors plugin code.

Comment: I saw that ACF has some controls over the Edit Vendor Page from the admin side, do you thing that can be useful?

Comment: Yes from the Admin side you will be able to add fields to the Vendor Taxonomy and still see the fields when editing a vendor, but for the Vendor Admin Dashboard, you will not be able to have those fields there to be editable by the Vendor. I have created a PHP Class that does the Job for simple fields(Not ACF). But you will need to understand PHP, do you?  Also what types of field are you trying to add?

Comment: The regular text, area and image fields to the Vendor Portfolio. I have used elementor template for Vendor Taxonomy (Vendor Profile), not using the default woocoomerce Vendor Profile, so i would like the Vendor to edit those fields on its own. Can you share what you have done with PHP, i know a little bit PHP to save my life. Thanks buddy for helping out !

Comment: Found this article on ACF 
[link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form_head/)

Comment: I have added here, they are far from perfect as I made quick, but I have tested and they work. But I haven't had the time to add the image fields type using the media library. https://github.com/martinezruiz9317/wc-product-vendors-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks @MiguelAngelMartinez , this is interesting! How would you integrate this code into the project? Should I modify the Product Vendor plugin? Thks

Comment: any clues please?